# Testing Exception handling

Tags: c#, nunit

I have to test the following code.

```
public void SampleMethod(FooBarObject fooBarObject) {
    try { 
        fooBarObject.Name = "Never forget a towel";
        fooBarObject.Number = 42;
    }
    catch (NullReferenceException){}
}
```

How can I test with NUnit whether an exception has been handled correctly?

Comment: Decorate your test method with [ExpectedException] attribute and provide the type of exception parameter. Send null values to the method which you are testing so that an exception is actually raised, the test will pass only if the exception is raised as it is expecting one.

Comment: side note: `catch (NullReferenceException){}` is a really **bad style**; check for `null` instead: `if (null == fooBarObject) return;`

Comment: Don't handle `NullReferenceException`s.

Comment: If I check for `null`, I can't test it, because I have no return value. And I don't want to add a return value only for the test.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The most idiomatic way of explicitly checking that no exceptions are thrown is by using the [Assert.DoesNotThrow](https://github.com/nunit/docs/wiki/Assert.DoesNotThrow) syntax.

As an example:

```
public class ClassUnderTest {
    public void SampleMethod(FooBarObject fooBarObject) {
        try { 
            fooBarObject.Name = "Never forget a towel";
            fooBarObject.Number = 42;
        }
        catch (NullReferenceException){}
    }
}

[Test]
public void Given_A_Class_Under_test_When_Calling_The_Sample_Method_It_Should_Not_Throw() {
    var sut = new ClassUnderTest();

    Assert.DoesNotThrow(() => sut.SampleMethod(null));
}
```

The caveat is that it's a bit of a catch-all, in that you're only asserting that no exceptions are thrown, not that the exception was handled in a certain way of the type of exception handled.

Having just seen CodeNotFound's answer, I would suggest going for his defensive coding approach, it's a common pattern to adopt and will really keep your methods as clean as possible. Check explicitly, fail early and deal with the fallout higher up the call chain, instead of just swallowing the null-reference exception.

Comment: Probably `Assert.DoesNotThrow(() => sut.SampleMethod(null));`

Comment: Thx, that solution is nice. I've added a log entry in the emty catch block.

Answer (score 3):

You have two options:

- Using `Assert.Throws` methods inside your test. Check this link: https://github.com/nunit/docs/wiki/Assert.Throws
- Decorate your test method with `ExpectedException` attribute. Not available starting version 3 of Nunit.

You should pass a `null` value so just call `SampleMethod(null)` for the act part of your test.

**Side Note n°1:** To make your test pass to green you need to rethrow the exception into your catch block by using `throw`.

**Side Note n°2:**
It really really rare to catch a `NullReferenceException`. You need to refactor your method and use a defensive coding like below:

```
public void SampleMethod(FooBarObject fooBarObject) {
    if (fooBarObject == null) {
        throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(fooBarObject));
    }

    fooBarObject.Name = "Never forget a towel";
    fooBarObject.Number = 42;
}
```

With code like you test that all argument are valid before using parameters of your method.

Comment: Also worth noting, Assert.Throws returns the exception object, and has generic overloads, so you can say Assert.Throws<ArgumentNullException>(//etc) and then check that the returned object mentions the right parameter or contains a certain string in its message.